# Record audio output through phone

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, record

I'm using the code4fun toolkit. I can record sound from the microphone. I'd also like to record sounds emitted from the phone (such as a song playing on YouTube in the background).

Is it possible to capture the audio output from a Windows phone? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't know the answer but I have a lot of experience asking and answering questions on this site. To help you get answers I've reworded your question. Hope this helps. Good luck with your karaoke game!

Comment: Thank for your edition! ^^ @PatrickMcElhaney